# Trigger.io Reload - Configs missing - can't reload my live app

Tags: reload, trigger.io

I'm using Trigger.io Reload to send an update out for my app.

The problem is when I go to the 'Reload' tab in the Trigger Toolkit, the config for my live app is not listed.

I click 'Show configs' and Configs for the last 28 days are listed, but no further back than that. My last build that was released that I want to reload was about 38 days ago.

Also none of the configs that are listed show any active users.

Help! Where did the configs go and how do I get them back so I can update my users?

I'm wondering if this is related to the recent Toolkit update to support multiple developers and projects? Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? I've just recreated what you see on that Reload view, and I see 58 entries, going back into November '12... If refreshing that page - maybe restart the Toolkit? - doesn't help, I can manually get all the configs you've built this app with, so we definitely get you up and running pushing Reload updates to your released app.

Comment: Yep, certain! Tried on three different machines with different logins to the same toolkit. We only see 19 entries. I emailed you a screenshot 9th Feb, another one here: http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/4683/temppf.png  Can you email me directly about this please?